# Sampler2d and samplerCube arrays in the same shader

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, glsles

I am trying to build a shader (in glsl 1.0) that uses an array of sampler2d textures, and an array of samplerCube textures. Strangely, I can't link it (and I can't get an error message) if I alternate the usage of the two textures. By trials and error, I located the code that caused the issue:

This fail to compile:

```
  varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
  varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord2;
  varying lowp vec3 vLighting;
  varying lowp vec4 vColor;
  varying lowp vec3 vNormal;

#ifdef Textures\r\n"
  uniform sampler2D uSampler[Textures];
  uniform lowp vec2 texFlag[Textures];
  uniform lowp mat3 texMat[Textures];
  uniform lowp float tex_coord_set[Textures];
  uniform samplerCube uSamplerC[Textures];
#endif

  uniform lowp vec3 fogColor;
  varying lowp float fogBlend;

  void main(void) {
#ifdef Textures
    mediump vec4 pixColor = vColor;
    mediump vec3 SpecNormal = reflect(vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0), vNormal);
    mediump vec4 texelColor;
          pixColor += textureCube(uSamplerC[0], vNormal);
          pixColor += texture2D(uSampler[0], vec2(0.0,0.0));
          pixColor += textureCube(uSamplerC[1], vNormal);
          pixColor += texture2D(uSampler[1], vec2(0.0,0.0));
else
    mediump vec4 pixColor = vColor;
#endif
```

But if I put:

```
  pixColor += textureCube(uSamplerC[0], vNormal);
  pixColor += textureCube(uSamplerC[1], vNormal);
  pixColor += texture2D(uSampler[0], vec2(0.0,0.0));
  pixColor += texture2D(uSampler[1], vec2(0.0,0.0));
```

(putting first all sampler of one type) it seems to link perfectly. Why?

(note: this code, in current form, is pointless, I used it only to expose the issue)

Comment: I believe that GLSL-ES has somewhat patchy support for arrays of samplers. I think they're supported as long as the index is static but might not be if the index is dynamic, so your code should be fine in theory. However, I have run into weird problems on some devices and ended up removing all sampler arrays from my Android codebase to avoid problems on some devices.

Comment: Unfortunately, looks like you are right.

Comment: For now,I solved by using a different name for each texture, and a lot of #ifdef pragmas. Not the best solution, but I figured that if support for sampler arrays is so bad, even if I could get my program to work on my computer it would have caused a lot of bugs on others.